# Showing the limit of an event is zero

Tags: probability

Let $\{ A_n \}_{n \geq 1 }$ be a sequence of events which are pairwise disjoint and let $P$ be a probability measure. Show carefully that $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_n) = 0$.

#### Attempt to the solution:

I need to show that for given $\epsilon > 0$ we can find Some $N > 0$ so that $P(A_n) < \epsilon $ for all $n > N$

We know $\{ A_n \}$ are pwdisjoint and since $P$ is a probability, we have

$$ P(A_n) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(A_n) = P \bigg( \bigcup_n A_n \bigg) \leq 1$$

Here I am stuck since I don't know what $N$ I should take. Can I just take $N > 1 $ ?

Comment: Take $N$ such that $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}P(A_k)<\epsilon$. Such $N$ exists. Then $P(A_n)\leq\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}P(A_k)<\epsilon$ for each $n\geq N$.

Comment: Why such an $N$ exists ? I don't get it.

Comment: If $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P\left(A_{k}\right)=c\leq1$ (wich is the case
here) then $\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}P\left(A_{k}\right)>c-\epsilon$ for $N$
large enough, so that $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}P(A_{k})=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(A_{k})-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}P(A_{k})<c-(c-\epsilon)=\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

$P(A_n)\leq\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}P(A_k)$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(A_k)\leq1$ implies that $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}P(A_k)\rightarrow0$ if $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

If the probabilities $P(A_n)$ do not converge to $0$ when $n\to\infty$ there is an $\epsilon_0>0$ and a subsequence $\bigl(A_{n_k}\bigr)_{k\geq1}$ with $P(A_{n_k})\geq \epsilon_0$ for all $k$. As the $A_{n_k}$ are pairwise disjoint the event $\bigcup_{k=1}^K A_{n_k}$ would then have a probability $>1$ if $K$ is large enough – a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Because of what  you have written (parwise disjoint events):

$$U_n:=\sum_{k=1}^nP(A_k)=P(\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k)\leq 1$$

So that $(U_n)$ is a bounded above sequence (by $1$). But because $P(*)\geq 0$ (it is a probability), $(U_n)$ is also an increasing sequence. So, we get that the sequence $(U_n)$ must converge.

This means that the serie $\sum P(A_k)$ is convergent, then by a usual argument on convergent series the term you sum must converge to $0$ (the converse is not true in general, by the way).